# Nginx: more_clear_headers alternative

Tags: nginx, module

I want to upgrade nginx manually to the stable version 1.9.
Currently version 1.4.X is installed from the ubuntu repos. In the ubuntu-package "nginx-extras" there is the nginx modul "more_clear_headers".
We use it to hide the "server" header.

In version 1.9 that comes directly from nginx, the module is not available.

Is there an "out of the box" alternative in nginx?
I don't want to compile nginx manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I believe you can try using `add_header server [VALUE]` to overwrite the existing value.

> The add_header directives, much like all other array-type directives in nginx, are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

https://serverfault.com/a/431189

---

Alternatively, you could possibly use [WordOps](https://github.com/WordOps/WordOps) to upgrade Nginx without the need to compile it.

Comment: no`add_header` will add another value to the existing value and I can't really use WordOps since there are several thing Nginx does for us - it delivers static content, acts as a load balancer + http cache with varnish.

Comment: Bummer. I can tell you I did a lot of research on this in the past and found only `more_clear_headers` as an option. Fwiw, WordOps can serve static content, and maybe can be integrated with your other tools with some work - but it's probably more than just compiling Nginx from source at that point.

Answer (score -2):

not yet available but perhaps in near feature DotDeb would have it...
https://www.dotdeb.org/category/nginx/

(I am actual also searching for alternative of this parameter but Nginx is soo fantastic - watch their videos how easy it's to configure in compare to other webservers - that there is no core need to remove headers like e.g. Apache does is since decades ;))

EDIT: https://github.com/gplessis/dotdeb-nginx/issues/70
=> he would wait for stable release because of other module incompatibilities.